# How do I start an empty breadcrumb?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I am modifying a module that extends `PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder`, but that only has methods to add a link at the end of the bread  and I want in certain cases to start the breadcrumb from scratch or add a link at the beginning of the breadcrumbs.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at [this documentation](http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-breadcrumb-drupal-8) and I think it says that you could start from scratch using:

```
$breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
```

And the class:

```
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb
```

Comment: I tried that but get this error Error: Class 'Drupal\pup_taxonomy_breadcrumb\Breadcrumb' not found

Comment: now I added use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb; And I get Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb' not found

Comment: The comment(s) say it does not work - yet it is accepted?

Comment: @Kevin I deleted the comments that led to the conclusion that she need the class `use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb`. Sorry, I should have kept them next time... :)

Answer (score 1):

In your custom PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder, you have to return true in the applies() method and additionally return your new Breadcrumb object in the build() method.

And you need this import

```
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb;
```

And in the services.yml of your module you must register the breadcrumb_builder plugin like so:

```
  preosasde.breadcrumb:
    class: Drupal\preosasde\PreosAsdeBreadcrumben
    arguments: ["@proreosservice", "@request_stack"]
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 100 }
```

Comment: Hi can you give me a link to the code for this applies method?